# Magento2 - Getting Issue in display multiselect category attribute options in Admin

Tags: magento, magento2, entity-attribute-value

In am trying to create multiselect category attribute from Installer script. The attribute is created. But I am getting the issue in option values in Magento 2 - Manage Category page. It only display blank textarea.

I have created this using below installer script:

```
/** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    /**
     * Add attributes to the eav/attribute for Category
     */

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'class',
        [
            'backend'      => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'type'         => 'varchar',
            'label'        => 'Class',
            'group'        => 'General Information',
            'input'        => 'multiselect',
            'source'       => '',
            'global'       => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'visible'      => true,
            'required'     => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order'   => 100,
            'option'     => [
                'value' => [
                    'SET' => ['SET'],
                    'HE'  => ['HE'],
                    'HBR' => ['HBR'],
                ]
            ],
        ]
    );
```

In database, I can see that, attribute is created in eav tables and option and values also there.

For fixing this, I have added xml in my custom module which has below xml(..\view\adminhtml\ui_component\category_form.xml).

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="class">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Class</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

But still getting issue in option values in admin category page. Textarea comes with no options. I have tried to cache:flush, static-content:deploy, setup:upgrade, indexer:reindex but still having issue. I am using Magento2.1.1 CE. Is there anything do I need to do? 
[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should fix the `option` key in your configuration array like shown below:

```php
'option' => [
    'values' => ['SET', 'HE', 'HBR'],
],
```

The `values` key is used to add options, the `value` key instead is used to update options that already exists, so be careful with them.

For the full explanation, see the `addAttributeOption` method code in the `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup` class.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But the problem is for getting attribute options inside the admin category panel, which is again not solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
source is blank thats why it showing blank in multi select use   
 'source'        => 'modulename/modelname',

and in source file use 

public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array(array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Label'),
                'value' => 'value'
            ));
          }
        return $this->_options;
    }
```